# Short way to create arrays?

Tags: vb.net, arrays

In VB.NET, I create my arrays like

```
Dim myArray = New ArrayList
```

But isn't there a way to create an array with elements without having to make a variable?

In Ruby, the long way was

```
array = Array.new
```

And the simple, non-variable way was just

```
[element,element,...]
```

Comment: And how, exactly, would you _access_ such an array without a name to identify it.

Comment: So you can't? Ok then, thanks.

Comment: That's it? Is there something else you were trying to accomplish that we can help you with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, things you **can** do with primitive (and String) arrays:

```
Dim array As New String()
Dim array As New String() { "one", "two", "three" }

If (New String() { "one", "two", "three" }).Contains("one") Then
    ' Do something for "one"
End If
```

If you move to VB.NET 2010 you will get some extra array initialization features, but if you're using 2008 or below the shortest you can get your lists created might be something like this:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.AddRange(New String() { "one", "two", "three" })
```

And to touch on the point of declaring things without assigning them to a variable: .NET is strongly typed, so while you don't always have to declare a variable, your objects will always need to be of a single type (and one you need to specify through a `New`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure just how useful such a beast is since, without a name, you can't easily access the elements of it.

I know C has a feature that allows this with "one-shot" accesses like:

```
char hexchar = "0123456789abcdef"[nybble];
```

but, after that statement's finished the char array making up that string is no longer accessible.

If you want an array you can access continuously, I suspect it will need an identifying name. I might be wrong, I haven't used VB since VB6 but even if it's possible, it's a dubious language feature (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim xs = New Integer() {1, 2, 3}

    CType({1, 2, 3}, Integer()).CopyTo(...)

    Dim s2 = Sum({1, 2, 3})

End Sub

Public Function Sum(ByVal array As Integer()) As Integer
    Return array.Sum()
End Function
```

Is this the kind of thing you're after?

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each foo As String In New String() {"one", "two", "three"} 'an array with no name - "On the first part of the journey..."
        Debug.WriteLine(foo)
    Next
```