# Initialize ArrayList WITH elements

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Short way to create arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812972/short-way-to-create-arrays)

I can create an ArrayList, but, is it possible to create it WITH some elements already?
Normally, your arrays are empty, but what if I want to create an array with a few elements already?

Comment: That makes no sense. Create the ArrayList then fill it. Also, unless you're using .NET 1.1 or below, don't use ArrayList. Use `List<object>` instead.

Comment: Didn't you just ask almost the same question over here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812972/short-way-to-create-arrays

Comment: Whom marked this question as duplicate, obviously didn't knew the difference between an arraylist and a list of strings. So sad.

Comment: @JohnSaunders That is not the VB.NET notation for a generic (see below)!

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Of course, the VB.NET syntax is `List(Of Object)`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders NP, also, if your using .NET 2.0 or older there are no List objects, generic or not. U need to use arrays, `Dim a() as New Integer`, or `ArrayList`'s... I've been doing ASP.NET web sites in VS2005/.NET2.0

Comment: @SamusArin: wrong. Generics are part of .NET 2.0.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for clarifying Mr. John... So it looks like there is no non-generic List in 2.0, but there is a generic version. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections(v=vs.80).aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @SamusArin: both lists still exist.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Oh I didn't know you were a .NET architect. Such an assured statement simply cannot come from anyone with less experience, unless of course that person is a common practitioner. Let me ask then, have you ever targeted the .NET 2.0 framework using VB.NET code from a Visual Studio 2005 project?

Comment: @SamusArin: VS 2005 targets .NET 2.0 by default and to make it do otherwise requires changes that you cannot make through the projects settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is out. This works:

```
Dim list as List(Of String) = 
    New List(Of String)(New String() {"one", "two", "three"})
```

Comment: A List is-not an ArrayList though!

Comment: @SamusArin: True, but arguably, no one should be using `ArrayList` for anything, and given the accepted answer does not use them, the asker must have been okay with it.

Comment: @Cory Both of your arguments are completely inconsequential to the fact that the OP asks about `ArrayList`'s (look at title of page) . Why does that matter you may ask, b/c I just came across this page searching google for "initializing ArrayList's"... I'm not downvoting anyone, jus sayin.

Comment: @Cory Also, I'm using `ArrayList`'s b/c it's all I have available in my projects, which are in VS2005 targeting .NET 2.0 (not my decision, incase you ask "why r u using such an old version...").

Comment: The version of visual studio doesn't not dictate the .NET platform being targeted. However, a given version of VS is limited to target only the platforms that were available to it (which are usually time dictated).

Comment: @SamusArin: I understand your points. The answer here and in the duplicate question are simply showing the easiest and best alternative for something that doesn't actually exist. Rather than give the answer "there isn't a way to do what you're asking," it seemed a better option to show what *is* available. Also, [generic lists were definitely available in .NET 2.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.80).aspx), but collection initializers were not.

Comment: New ArrayList({"one", "two"})

Answer (score 9):

In VB.NET 2010, you can do things like:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From { "one", "two", "three" }
```

In 2008 and below you're stuck with initializing your lists after you've instantiated them.

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("one")
list.Add("two")
list.Add("three")
```

Or you could shorten it up a bit and do this (this won't work if you declare your `List(Of T)` as an `IList(Of T)`):

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.AddRange(New String() { "one", "two", "three" })
```

Comment: +1 although VB.Net 2010 is [out](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Basic), and it has been for months :)

Comment: Ya, whoops! Edited out the fallacy.

Comment: A List is-not an ArrayList though!